# cocos2dx incorrect image on iphone 3g

Tags: image, cocos2d-x

I use cocos2dx for my game, and it work fine in all devices(iPad 1-3, Iphone4+), but it work bad on Iphone 3g(3gs).

Why do cocos2dx load some images incorrect?

please, see this img(correct img): http://cl.ly/image/1H0q3S0u0B2P and incorrect img: http://cl.ly/image/3s2G1T31370b

Comment: both links point to the same image

Comment: Have same thing - trying this one http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/faq but no results... No ideas...